# An NSManagedObject of class 'Grapevine_2017.SearchEntity' must have a valid NSEntityDescription

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

receiving the error - An NSManagedObject of class 'Grapevine_2017.SearchEntity' must have a valid NSEntityDescription

i've looked at all the other stack over flow solutions and still can not solve it.

the name for my data model is Grapevine_2017.xcdatamodeld

here is my code

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class persistenceService {

// MARK: - Core Data stack


private init() {}

static var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
    return persistentContainer.viewContext
}

static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Grapevine_2017")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {


            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

static func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {


            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
}



 public class SearchEntity: NSManagedObject {

}


 extension SearchEntity {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<SearchEntity> {
    return NSFetchRequest<SearchEntity>(entityName: "SearchEntity")
    }

@NSManaged public var distance: String?

 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An NSManagedObject of class 'SearchEntity' must have a valid NSEntityDescription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47133911/error-nsinvalidargumentexception-reason-an-nsmanagedobject-of-class-search)

Comment: Please don't duplicate your own question - if you wish to amend or add to it, edit the original.